# Open XML SDK For Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, sdk, ms-word

I'm using Open XML SDK for javascript...

I downloaded it from [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org)

I create word document and save it on desktop with this SDK...

now I want do modify content of this document

for example: if in the text is word "firstname", I want to change this word with "John" and so on...

second what I want is that before I save document put it in .rar or .zip file and then save it like .rar on desktop

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

> if in the text is word "firstname", I want to change this word with "John" and so on...

- [Search and Replace Method](http://ericwhite.com/blog/search-and-replace-text-in-an-open-xml-wordprocessingml-document/)

> second what I want is that before I save document put it in .rar or .zip file and then save it like .rar on desktop

- Rename the .docx file to .zip, since they are [one and the same](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15593/Read-and-write-Open-XML-files-MS-Office-2007):

> every Open XML file is essentially a Zip archive containing many other files. Office-specific data is stored in multiple XML files inside that archive. This is in direct contrast with the old WordML and SpreadsheetML formats which were single, non-compressed XML files. Although more complex, the new approach offers a few benefits:

**References**

- [Open XML search and replace (searchandreplace.zip)](http://openxmldeveloper.org/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-00-14-83-57/SearchAndReplace.zip)
- [OpenXmlSimpleType members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.openxmlsimpletype_members)

Answer (score 0):

Word, power point, Excel are just zip files them self with different extension. If you want to change strings in a excel file, look at the shared strings table where all the strings are stored and referenced by the sheets.